# PHP Mailer: I'm getting an error "Could not access file" while trying to upload the file through form and sending it as a attachment

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

**Here's The PHP Code**
I'm able to send the mail. If I comment out the $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
$category = $_POST['category'];
$attachment = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
$query = "select Name, email, status, category from mailer where status='subscribed' and category='$category'";
$result = $conn->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = $row['Name'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $category1 = $row['category'];


    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              
    try {                               
         //send code
        //Recipients
        $mail->addAddress($email);
        $mail->AddAttachment($attachment);
```

Comment: You’re not handling the attachment safely, and nor is the posted answer. Look at the example provided with PHPMailer and the PHP docs on handling file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$attachment = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];` to `$attachment = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];` as `name` refers to the original file name and `tmp_name` to the (temporary) file path on the server. And you need to specify the file on the server in `AddAttachment()` call.

Comment: $file_to_attach = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$filename=$_FILES['attachment']['name'];
$mail->AddAttachment($file_to_attach , $filename);          

I've done this but still getting the same error.

Comment: Okay, what is written out when you put `var_dump($_FILES['attachment']);` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $message = 'This for sending an attachment by using php mailer';
    $Sender = 'youremail@xyz.com';      
    $subject = "Attachment Test";
    $Recipiant = 'recipient@xyz.com';
    $subject = $subject;
    $host= "yourdomain.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $port=465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $username="info@yourdomain.com";                   // GMAIL username
    $pwd="domain mail password";

    include 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->IsMail();
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host       = $host;      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = $port;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = $username;  // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password   = $pwd;            // GMAIL password
    $mail->AddReplyTo($Sender,"");
    $mail->From       = $Sender;
    $mail->FromName   = $SenderName;
    $mail->Sender     = $Sender;
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;

    $FileName = 'PRO1158.pdf';

    $mail->Body       = "<br>".$message."<br>";

    if($FileName!=""){
        $mail->AddAttachment("Invoices/".$FileName); // attach files
    }

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->WordWrap   = 50; // set word wrap
    //$mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->AddAddress("$Recipiant","");
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
    $mail->Send();
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
```

Comment: Really, your answer is too long to stand up as a code-only answer. It's best to explain what the issue is, and why your code fixes it (and in this case, which bit of your code)

Answer (score -1):

First you need to upload the file into a folder then place the file path in 
 `$mail->AddAttachment();`

exapmle :

```
$attachment="D:\uploads\img.jpg"
$mail->AddAttachment($attachment);
```